# Depicting memory when saving a C string to RAM

Tags: c, string

For my homework I had the following question:

> Bob used a pointer to save the C string “Wow! Amazing.” at address 100
>   subscript(16) in RAM. Depict the memory as a table with two columns.
>   The first column will be the address in RAM and the second column will
>   be the data stored at that address.
>
> Display the memory and it's contents in binary for the C string Bob
>   stored at 100 subscript(16). In other words: write the addresses in
>   binary and the bytes in binary for the given C string as a table
>   having two columns, the left-most column being the addresses.

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track. Would I simply convert the string, using ASCII, to binary and convert 100<sub>16</sub> to decimal which is 256. Then divide the string into 8 bit components and at address 256 put the first 8 bits (first letter), at address 257 put the 2nd 8 bits (2nd letter), and so forth?

Comment: Btw, the `homework` tag is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: Don't forget endianness matters.

Comment: @Vinska, endianness? For a string?

Comment: Also, why would you convert to decimal? It's 256 however you represent it.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes. It does matter for how it is laid out in the memory.

Comment: @Visnka, explain please.  I have never seen an ASCII string that depended in any way on endianness.  Actually, it's kind of by definition.  What are you saying happens?

Comment: Well, since the memory contents is to be dumped in binary, one could argue that [bit endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) does in fact matter. :)

Comment: @H2CO3 I suppose it was superfluous information.

Comment: I noticed that the homework doesn't make any requirements regarding character set. Does this mean you can make your own up? :D

Answer (score 3):

James used a pointer to save the C string “Test” at address 10 subscript(16) in RAM.

```
 Address    data
0001:0000  0101-0100
0001:0001  0110-0101
0001:0010  0111-0011
0001:0011  0111-0100
0001:0100  0000-0000
```

(I was doing the letter-to-ASCII-to-binary conversion in my head, so I may be off a bit)

(EDITED: Fixed dumb mistake as noted in comments)

Comment: A *C* string should likely include a terminator character.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought.

Comment: @user2019594 If your question is answered, please take the time to [accept the most deserving answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), thus symbolically rewarding the volunteer who took their time to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct.

However, this isn't probably a very useful question on SO.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't sure exactly where to post this type of question. Thanks for your help though.